# Why is the hidden field in the Laravel Model not working when set dynamically?

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I am writing a function in the model where I need a data something like this.

`{"id": 1, "level_id": "1"}`

So, the query is something like this:

```
public function showAdvancedRoutes(array $requestArray = [], $journey_id = null, $level_id = null) {
    $queryResults = $this -> with(['level' => function ($query) use($journey_id, $level_id) {
        $query -> where('levels.level_number', $level_id)
            -> where('levels.journey_id', $journey_id);
    }]) -> get() ;
    return (sizeof($queryResults) == 0) ? null : ((sizeof($queryResults) > 1) ? ["Multiple Records. Please contact developer."] : $queryResults[0]);
}
```

where

`public function level() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Level', 'level_id');
    }`

Now THE REAL PROBLEM IS:

when I write, `protected $hidden = ['level'];` I the desired results of `{"id": 1, "level_id": "1"}`. 
But, when I do something like this:

```
public function showAdvancedRoutes(array $requestArray = [], $journey_id = null, $level_id = null) {
    $this -> setHidden(['level']);
    //#query logic
}
```

I get, 
`{"id": 1, "level_id": "1", "level": {"id": 1}}`.

So, my real doubt is why is the hidden attribute not working while Query building?

In both cases, whether I write `protected $hidden = ['level'];` or I `setHidden` dynamically, the dump of the model is same.

```
["hidden":protected]=>array(1){[0]=>string(5) "level"}
```

But, I am getting results different in two cases. Is this a bug or an I doing something wrong?

Comment: what is happening in that last example with the stuff you removed `//#query logic`, what are you actually returning from that method?

Comment: `$queryResults = $this -> with(['level' => function ($query) use($journey_id, $level_id) {
        $query -> where('levels.level_number', $level_id)
            -> where('levels.journey_id', $journey_id);
    }]) -> get() ;`

The same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting hidden on a particular model instance, via `setHidden`. You are then querying the database to get a new collection or model back. Setting these things on one model instance does not affect other model instances.

The `hidden` property of the model is not a static property. Every single Model instance has its own `hidden` property array.

Comment: I am not sure. Becuase I am 
`$queryResults = $this -> with(['level' => function ($query) use($journey_id, $level_id) {
        $query -> where('levels.level_number', $level_id)
            -> where('levels.journey_id', $journey_id);
    }]) -> get() ;`
I am quering from the same instance using `$this ->` for the same instance of the model.
I tried to `dd($this)` before and after setting `$this -> setHidden()`. And the `dd($this)` after shows it sets the `hidden` with the variable I am setting.

Comment: Your 'assumption' is incorrect. These queries return new objects (you are using a query builder, not the model to query), they have nothing to do with that original instance of the model at that point. They return NEW instances. Every model instance has its own `hidden` property, no other model instance affects another model instance's `hidden` property.

Comment: Yes, I got the same explanation from [GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18372).